# Website looks different on a Mac

Tags: css, firefox

I have just created a website which looks fine on firefox PC but looks totally different on Firefox Mac.

On Mac I don't see a div background image.
On mac in the footer, an item that is floated to the left appears on the right and an item that is floated to the right appears on the left.

A facebook div that I have commented with `<!--` appears on Mac but not on PC.

The site is: http://www.ruthrudin.co.il

Can anyone help with these problems?

Comment: My guess is that Firefox shows an older cached copy. Have you tried to do a hard reload (cmd-f5)?

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the refresh. I have just opened the site on a mac that never displayed this site before.

Answer (score 3):

I only briefly had a chance to look at the source, but did notice that on line 66 you illegally nest an HTML comment `<!--  </div><!--`. Your usage of `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">` is invalid and should match how you did the jquery `<script type="text/javascript">your code here</script>`.

Run your code through a validator. The browsers do differ in how they handle invalid markup across operating systems, even from the same vendor.

Comment: Here's a link to the site with the w3c validator http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ruthrudin.co.il%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I have managed to fix the background image display by adding in the css: min-height: 600px
I am a bit confused, since I don't see <!--</div><!-- on line 66. Still trying to find it.

I fixed the javascript to the right syntax, it is a code I have downloaded and wasn't aware of this problem.

Comment: Now I see the background image, but I still see the facebook button and I still see items floating in the wrong direction, and I don't see a whole section of the footer: סטודיו בוטיק לעיצוב גרפי, עיצוב לדפוס ולאינטרנט, עיצוב מגזינים, עיצוב לוגו וכרטיסי ביקור, מיתוג, הפקות דפוס, עיצוב קטלוגים,
עיצוב חוברות, עיצוב מודעת פרסום, עיצוב פלאיירים, עיצוב אתרים ודפי נחיתה
I am not a Mac user so not sure how to use most of it, any validator you can recommend to me?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, found the problems with the background image, removed the inner div that was the problem but I still have the problem with Webmaster: Sigal Zahavi that should be on the left and not on the right. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, thanks to user903526 all is fixed, thank very very much. I learned a new very usefull thing today, the validator. I am very graetful and will use this validator from now on.